# Porque LINQ to Entities no reconoce el metodo 'System.String PadLeft(Int32, Char)'

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

Estoy intentado compilar mi codigo pero me sale el siguiente error

> Excepción producida: 'System.NotSupportedException' en
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
>
> Se produjo una excepción de tipo 'System.NotSupportedException' en
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll pero no se controló en el código del
>   usuario
>
> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   PadLeft(Int32, Char)' method, and this method cannot be translated
>   into a store expression.

Trato de obtener la informacion desde la base de datos para ser procesados y presentados en un Datatable, estoy usando **LINQ** y **Entity Framework**

```
IQueryable<TicketsResult> query;

                if (string.Equals(Session["tipo"].ToString(), "admin", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                    string.Equals(Session["tipo"].ToString(), "mesa", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    query = TicketListModel.ConsultTicketListAll(db); 
                }
                else
                {
                    query = TicketListModel.ConsultTicketListTech(Session["matricula"].ToString(), db); 
                }

                var totalCount = query.Count();
```

Esta es la Query donde obtengo la informacion desde la BD

```
public static IQueryable<TicketsResult> ConsultTicketListAll(dbGoldenTicket db)
        {
            return from tblTicket in db.TK_HD_TICKETS
                join tblRecord in db.TK_DT_RECORDS on tblTicket.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID equals tblRecord.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID
                join tblServices in db.TK_CT_SERVICES on tblRecord.TK_CT_SERVICES_ID equals tblServices.TK_CT_SERVICES_ID
                join tblStatus in db.TK_CT_STATUS on tblRecord.TK_CT_STATUS_ID equals tblStatus.TK_CT_STATUS_ID
                where tblRecord.TK_DT_RECORDS_ID == (
                          from tblTicketAux in db.TK_HD_TICKETS
                          join tblRecordAux in db.TK_DT_RECORDS on tblTicketAux.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID equals tblRecordAux.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID
                          where tblTicket.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID == tblTicketAux.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID
                          select tblRecordAux.TK_DT_RECORDS_ID
                      ).Max()
                select new TicketsResult()
                {
                    TicketCode = tblTicket.TK_CT_AREAS_ID + "-" + tblTicket.CREATE_DATE.Year +
                                 tblTicket.CREATE_DATE.Month.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') +
                                 tblTicket.CREATE_DATE.Day.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') +
                                 tblTicket.SEQUENCE_NUMBER.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0'),
                    TicketAplicant = tblTicket.CUSTOMER_FULLNAME,
                    TicketSubjet = tblTicket.TITLE,
                    TicketStatus = tblStatus.NAME,
                    TicketService = tblServices.NAME,
                    TicketEmployee = tblRecord.TK_BT_EMPLOYEES_ID
                };
        }
```

Comment: Porque esa la clase `String` no es soportada para `IQueryable`, mejor utiliza `DbFunctions`, aquí la documentación de esta clase: [DbFunctions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbfunctions?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)

Comment: El método que ocupas es `DbFunctions.Left()` es el equivalente a `PadLeft()` compatible. Aquí la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.left?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#System_Data_Entity_DbFunctions_Left_System_String_System_Nullable_System_Int64__)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El método que ocupas es `DbFunctions.Left()` es el equivalente a `PadLeft()` compatible.

Aquí la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.left?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#System_Data_Entity_DbFunctions_Left_System_String_System_Nullable_System_Int64__)

Si ocupas mas funciones para LINQ no dudes en revisar la documentación de [DbFunctions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbfunctions?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)